# I don't have role option in my GitHub repository

Tags: github

I should have a role option as it is in GitHub tutorial.

[image]

Instead I have this:

[image]

How can I unlock this option?

I tried to make a repository public. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that for [personal accounts](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/access-permissions-on-github#personal-accounts) there are only two types of permission levels: `repository owner` and `collaborators`. To get more roles, you have to have an [organization account](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/access-permissions-on-github#organization-accounts). It might be the case that their documentation hasn't been updated.